# last record of php (json) on an array then add 1

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I did this question before but I have new data to make me understand.
I need to know how to get the last record of an array in php for a web service? I need to get it, add 1 and then create a new register (with the number+1 in another record

```
id    turnoActual  
106       7
```

get the last number, add 1 and then add another record with the number added (automatic, no adding new parameters with the AndroidStudio) and then get it at the result. So, I get the 7, add one, put into the SQL and then get the 8 as the result variable.

```
id   turnoActual
106    7
107    8
```

Ty for the help, my regards, Santiago.

Code in php is like this and Im stuck and I dont know where to see.

ultimoTurno = LastTurn
nuevoTurno = newTurn

```
 <?PHP
    $hostname_localhost ="xxxxxxx";
    $database_localhost ="xxxxx";
    $username_localhost ="xxxxx";
    $password_localhost ="xxxxx";

    $json=array();



    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $ultimoTurno="select MAX(turnoActual) from tn";



    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$ultimoTurno);

    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $nuevoTurno=$registro['turnoActual']+1;
        $atendido=false;

        $nuevoTurno_query="INSERT INTO tn(turnoAcutal, atendido) VALUES ('{$nuevoTurno}','{$atendido}')";
        $resultado2=mysqli_query($conexion,$nuevoTurno_query);


        if($resultado2){
            $confirmacion="SELECT turnoActual FROM tn WHERE turnoActual = '{$nuevoTurno}'";
            $resultado3=mysqli_query($conexion,$confirmacion);

            if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado3)){
                $json['usuario'][]=$registro;
            }
            else{
                $result["turnoactual"]='no registra de resultado 3';
                $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
            }

        }
        else{
            $resulta["turnoAcutal"]='No Registra de resultado 2';
            $json['usuario'][]=$resulta;
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);








        }else{
            $resulta["turnoAcutal"]='No Registra de resultado';
            $json['usuario'][]=$resulta;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }

    ?>
```

[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wxnw.gif)

Comment: Can you give a sample on the json for us to work with?

Comment: I think I added the php file at the end of the consult (with the json on it). What file do you want me to upload? ty.

Comment: Just edit your question and add some part of the json or array you are asking help about.

Comment: I added an explanation at the end of the thread to picture what Im doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this over and over in phpMyAdmin:

```
INSERT INTO tn (turnoActual) SELECT IFNULL(MAX(turnoActual) + 1, 1) FROM tn
```

This will work without error regardless of if there are any rows in the table.  When there are no rows, the default value of `1` is applied.

It is advisable to lock your table before performing this query to avoid a race condition.

If you need to grab the data from your newly added row, use php's [insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

---

This answer assumes that you have been truthful about the number of columns (2) in your table and that the `id` column is PRIMARY and AUTOINCREMENT.

Hmm, your coding attempt references `atendido` but you won't be able to save `false` -- you *can* save `null` though.  If you make that column nullable and don't reference it in the INSERT, it will default to `NULL` which should be sensible for your project.

---

I also want to point out that `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array with indexed and associative elements.  If you only want to store the associative keys in your output, then use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

---

Here's a little sample snippet to get you started (I tested this locally to be successful; no table locking implemented):

```
if (!$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbname")) {  // declare and check for a falsey value
    echo "Connection Failure"; // $conexion->connect_error <-- never show actual error details to public
} elseif (!$conexion->query("INSERT INTO tn (turnoActual) SELECT IFNULL(MAX(turnoActual) + 1, 1) FROM tn
")) {  // execute and check for a falsey return value
    echo "Insert Failure - Syntax Error"; // $conexion->error  <-- never show query or actual error details to public
} elseif (!$result = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tn WHERE id = " . $conexion->insert_id)) {
    echo "Select Failure - Syntax Error"; // $conexion->error  <-- never show query or actual error details to public
} else {
    echo "<pre>";
        var_export($result->fetch_row());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is a really good answer, that is what I was looking for. That really helps a lot. Thank you for the time, your comments (in both publications) and the patience.

Comment: I've just added a working snippet to give you a boost.

Comment: Ive tried it and it created the number on the db. that was really nice to have it working and because I can compare what you did to continue with the work. Really ty. 

Image of the number created:
https://imgur.com/a/WBwOPsW

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last item with end().

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$last = end($arr);
$arr[] = $last+1;
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/eaLg2

Comment: Okay.. I get it, you are decoding the json to php, then going to the last number of the array and adding one "element", and then how can I put it into the database again? then I need to code the array to Json again and only put the last number on the db? There is a command to do that?

I get it but I dont know where to put it on the lines and what to do after.

Comment: And I can use the same example to an associative array? Because the mysqli_fetch_array gives me an associative one. Im going to try in a bit to resolve by doing this and when I have it, I will see how it comes. Ty for the help. Usefull

Comment: Again, just post the array/Json and i will give you a code that works exactly as you expect. But I can't guess what your array looks like

Comment: My db is empty, this is for generating a new turn, when I press a button on an Android app, I need to send the request to generate a new turn (automatic), so, if my db is empty I need to create the first turn, (turn 1). The only php json code im using is the one I put in the thread (with the explanation of what Im trying to do at the end of the thread on a picture) I dont have another array that the one who creates the json decode from the database. Im just using the data of SQL, its not that Im hiding information or something like that. Then I need to recieve the number on the Android app.

Comment: Ok! I give up. Good luck

Comment: Sorry I didnt understood what you were asking. Thank you anyway. Good luck!

Comment: Ive just deleted it, I didnt knew that was possible. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I did, but couldnt did it with that, perhaps Im just not getting it. I just dont know how to continue and That question didnt had my code. I had the pages people gave me on favorites but I dont know what to use where, and Im trying to get it. Its my first web service and Im failing hard. (I already had that working on SQL with java, for example, but not on a web service with php).